# Bumblebee Ball Python - striking food but missing

Tags: snakes

Started with the most recent feeding, my Bumblebee Ball Python has been hunting and striking at its prey but missing. I can't get her to eat frozen thawed, so I have been giving her live with no issues up until this feeding. She will go after the prey maybe three times and miss each time. I usually feed her in her enclosure, so I bought a new one, put her in it just to feed her, and then put a medium/large rat in with her and still had issues.

I waited another day or two and tried to feed her again. She see the rat, then slowly moves, then strikes and misses. None of the other pythons I have (that are smaller than my bumblebee) are having issues with similar size rats.

She's about almost two. She does have a [wobble](https://wheremyscalesslither.weebly.com/the-spider-morph-and-the-wobble.html). She is in a clear tubs; I am not sure if that is related to the issue.

Comment: I cleaned up your question to make it more clear; if I've changed your meaning behind anything in my edits, please feel free to edit or add back more information.

Comment: Can you tell us how she misses? Does she strike short of the prey, or wide? In the case of short, are you sure it's not a defensive strike?

Comment: If it's wide, it *might* be caused by the wobble, but I haven't heard about that before.

Comment: she does not strike shot and looks wide. She goes after the rat. I even used a small rat I usually feed a large one. But misses every time. So i try again in next couple of days. Since she will not eat frozen/thawed makes it hard to help her.